# list files in folder matching an exact filename

Tags: r

I have a number of files in my folder, e.g.:

- file1.txt
- file1.txt_sub
- file1.txt_sub2

I only wish R to find "file1.txt". But if I use

```
list.files(pattern = "file1.txt")
```

R will also return the other two files from my example. Any ideas how I could solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use regular expressions (see `?regex`):

```
list.files(pattern = "^file1\\.txt$")
```

`^` is the regular expression denoting the beginning of the string,
`\\` escapes the `.` to make it a literal `.`,
`$` is the regular expression denoting the end of the string.

In sum, this is the regular expression capturing exactly `file1.txt` and nothing else.